# mosaic or spine plot with fixed width?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

Mosaic plots or spine plots have width that depend on the # of data in that bin for ex:

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

Is there anyway to disable this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use prop.table and then barplot :

barplot(t(prop.table(M,1)))